# Converting an object in a loop to element and add it to the existing result

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.each(data, function(i,item){
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', item.thumb);
    img.attr('width', item.width);
    img.attr('height', item.height);
    o += '<li><a href="#">'+img+'<h3>'+item.title+'</h3><p>'+item.excerpt+'</p></a></li>';
});
```

The above outputs

```
li>[object] <h3>title</h3><p>excerpt</p></li>
```

My problem is with image tag. I understand that I am just appending a image object rather than the element... and using appendto would work but in the above scenario, in a loop, how do I accomplish this. Instead of displaying [object] how can display the image tag.

Comment: You are mixing DOM nodes and strings. That can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to get the html out of the object. there's a dozen or more ways to do that. one way is `img[0].outerHTML` which gives you the raw DOM element in the jQuery selector object, and then the outer html of that element.

```
$.each(data, function(i,item){
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', item.thumb);
    img.attr('width', item.width);
    img.attr('height', item.height);
    o += '<li><a href="#">'+img[0].outerHTML+'<h3>'+item.title+'</h3><p>'+item.excerpt+'</p></a></li>';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a poor way to modify the DOM. You should use normal DOM methods so you don't get into this mess.

However, if you **must** do it that way.

The problem caused is an object's `toString()` being implicitly called which is specified to return `[object [[Class]]` where `[[Class]]` is the internal class of the object. That's why you get `[object Object]` instead of the HTML of the `img` element.

You could get the *outer HTML like so...*

```
var imgOuterHtml = img.prop('outerHTML')
                   || '<img ' + 
                      []
                       .reduce
                       .call(img.prop('attributes'),
                             function(attrSerialised, attr) {
                                 return attrSerialised + 
                                        ' ' + attr.nodeName + 
                                        '="' + attr.nodeValue + '"';
                             },
                        '')
                       + '/>';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjKh5/).

It also looks like you can use `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(element)` if the `outerHTML` property does not exist, but it will only ever return XML, e.g. empty elements are always empty.

You could also create a temporary element such as a `div`, set its `innerHTML` and then get the outer `div`'s `innerHTML`.

But, **please**, don't do it this way. Use jQuery's wrapped DOM modifying methods.